# how to make circle on html div with some text?

Tags: html, css

[image: img]

As shown in image, I want to draw a circle on div, I have tried to get it done by using border-radius property.
and pasting a circle on div using position, but not getting perfect result
Please suggest me

Comment: where is your tried code...?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need adequately explain to us what you need, what you have tried so far, and show us the problematic code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some thing like this?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a0ybpce/)

```css
.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #666;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: -40px;
}
p{
  font-weight: bold;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
p span{
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: .5em
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle">
     <p>20%<span>OFF</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I have tried this but i want to place this circle on div at right side

Comment: I edited my answer